# I cannot get a class method working; if I copy-paste the method code where the method should be called, it works

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, pygame

I'm relatively new at programming my own classes in Python.
I work on a program in which I have already defined 3 classes with 4/5 methods each which are perfectly working. But I'm encountering a problem with a new one for an hour and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. In fact, the method doesn't work even though there are not a error message that pops up, but if I copy-paste the code of the method in my pygame loop (where it is called), it works perfectly fine.
Here's the code of my class (the .click(self) method being the one at stake here):

```
class button:
    def __init__(self, window, xpos, ypos, width, height, color = white, text = '', dest = None):
        self.xpos = xpos * r
        self.ypos = ypos * r
        self.width = width * r
        self.height = height * r
        self.color = color
        self.colorBuffer = [color[i] for i in range(3)]
        self.window = window
        self.hovered = False
        self.clicked = False
        self.text = text
        self.dest = dest
        #self.R = color[0]
        #self.G = color[1]
        #self.B = color[2]
    
    def click(self):
        self.clicked = True
        if self.dest == None:
            pass
        else:
            currentMenu = self.dest
            self.dest.disp()
            self.clicked = False
```

Here's the code where the method is called (it's called when the program checks if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN):

```
loop = False
if loop == False:
    currentMenu = mainMenu
loop = True
boxisinputting = False
boxinputting = None
userisinputting = False

while loop == True:
    pygame.display.flip()
    userisinputting = False
    mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    currentMenu.disp()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            loop = False
            pygame.quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if pygame.key.name(event.key) == 'return':
                boxinputting.inputting = False
                boxisinputting = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                for but in currentMenu.buttonList:
                    if but.hovered == True:
                        but.click()
                if boxisinputting == False:
                    for box in currentMenu.inputBoxList:
                        if box.hovered == True:
                            box.inputting = True
                            boxisinputting = True
                            boxinputting = box
    if userisinputting == True:
        boxinputting.render()
    pygame.time.delay(100)
```

What happens when I run this code:
The next menu displays fine, but its buttons aren't responding (I have methods that light it up or down whether the mouse in on the button); instead, it is the buttons of the previous menu that pop up when I move my pointer where they were.
However, when I copy-paste the instructions I want my method .click(self) to do here:

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    if event.button == 1:
        for but in currentMenu.buttonList:
            if but.hovered == True:
                but.clicked = True
                if but.dest == None:
                    pass
                else:
                    currentMenu = None
                    currentMenu = but.dest
                    but.dest.disp()
                    but.clicked = False
```

... well, it works perfectly fine: the buttons are active and responding, and the previous ones don't pop up out of nowhere (which is what I'm willing to do).
I could get away with it, because this would just waste 5 ou 6 lines in my loop. But I'm interested in knowing why I can't get the method working, in order to avoid future issues like this one.

Thank you for reading my post!

William

Comment: Okay, so *what exactly goes wrong*? Also, instead of trying to shorten the `click` method where you are having the problem, can you try to cut out *all the other stuff* that is not related to the problem? Only leave what is necessary so that other people can copy and paste the code and replicate the problem. Please see http://sscce.org for details.

Comment: If you replace your `break` with `button.click()` then your code with the function call would be equivalent to the in-line code. Otherwise, you're trying to call `button.click()` at the end of the `for` loop. And your `for` loop also has a potential issue, in that you're creating a local variable with the name `button`, the same name as your class. Does that help?

Comment: @Karl Knetchel Thanks. I've updated my post to make it hopefully more readable and to get straight to the point.

Comment: @Random Davis Well, you have pinpointed my problem: two codes that I consider equivalent do not run the same. And I've fixed the bad writing you're pointing out, replacing "for button in currentMenu.buttonList" by "for but in currentMenu.buttonList". It still doesn't adress my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell, because the included code does not show the instantiation of a `button`, but probably you need to ensure it's referencing the global scope:

```
def click(self):
    global currentMenu, gamesMenu
    currentMenu = gamesMenu
    print('click')
```

Your button class would be better if it would just stick to being *only* a button. So that's about the location, and the label, colours, whether it's clicked, unclicked, hovered, etc.  But what it is *not* is also important.  A button is not a menu, it shouldn't know about menus, and it shouldn't handle menus (or flush the display buffer!).

Objects produce better designs and cleaner code when they're concise about what they do.

Comment: thank you. I did not know about the "global" in Python, but I had identified the problem as: it modifies the currentMenu only locally in the method, but currentMenu takes it previous value once the program has finished running the method. So this adresses my issue. Also, concerning my button class, its aim is to point towards a menu when clicked, and to highlight when hovered: instead of writing functions and defining a button with a list, I found it more practical to define a class with its own methods. But feel free to give me advice to improve the ergonomy of my program.